# Converting a CollectionChanged event handler line from C# to VB.net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, events

I've used the [developerfusion C# to VB conversion tool](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) to convert [Brad Smith's ComboTreeBox](http://www.brad-smith.info/blog/archives/193) project and I'm having troubles on, as is fairly normal for me and C#-to-VB conversions, an event handler.

In the interface implementation for `IList(Of ComboTreeNode).Item` there is this C# code:

```
#region IList<ComboTreeNode> Members

public ComboTreeNode this[int index] {
    get {
        return innerList[index];
    }
    set {
        ComboTreeNode oldItem = innerList[index];
        innerList[index] = value;
        value.Parent = node;
        value.Nodes.CollectionChanged += CollectionChanged;
        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace, value, oldItem));
    }
}
```

which converts to

```
Public Default Property Item(index As Integer) As ComboTreeNode Implements IList(Of ComboTreeNode).Item, IList.Item
    Get
        Return innerList(index)
    End Get
    Set
        Dim oldItem As ComboTreeNode = innerList(index)
        innerList(index) = value
        value.Parent = node
        value.Nodes.CollectionChanged += CollectionChanged
        OnCollectionChanged(New NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace, value, oldItem))
    End Set
End Property
```

I'm getting errors on the last two lines of the Set method and frankly I don't understand what's even being done, there. It appears, from my limited C# events knowledge, to be adding an event handler back onto the event itself, which leaves me completely lost.

Doing a naive conversion to `AddHandler value.Nodes.CollectionChanged, AddressOf CollectionChanged` just brings up a reminder that the second argument of `AddHandler` needs to be a method address.

I'm stumped, here. What am I missing?

Comment: What sort of errors are you getting on the last two lines?

Comment: Sorry. "Public Event CollectionChanged(sender As Object, e As System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs)' is an event, and cannot be called directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event."

Comment: ...and did you try using RaiseEvent to raise the OnCollectionChanged?

Comment: The OnCollectionChanged line isn't the one raising the error, the CollectionChanged line is raising the error. I'm trying to get answers as to what the C# code is trying to do, not trying to randomly change code I don't understand until the error message goes away and because I don't know what the C# code is trying to do, I can't search for anything...

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe VB.NET has any way to combine events like that, so you may have to tweak it to use multicast delegates. I won't be testing this code, but we can debug it as we go.

First, in ComboTreeNodeCollection, change the CollectionChanged event to `Public CollectionChanged As NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler`.

For all of `value.Nodes.CollectionChanged += CollectionChanged`, change it to `value.Nodes.CollectionChanged = [Delegate].Combine(value.Nodes.CollectionChanged, CollectionChanged)`.
For -=, use `value.Nodes.CollectionChanged = [Delegate].Remove(value.Nodes.CollectionChanged, CollectionChanged)`.

Finally (hopefully), for `Protected Overridable Sub OnCollectionChanged`, change `CollectionChanged(Me, e)` (or however it looks) to `CollectionChanged.Invoke(Me, e)`.

<strike>Oh and you may want to add methods to replace AddHandler and RemoveHandler.</strike> Actually, I just had an idea where you can create a custom event that combines and removes from the delegate; you would still need to implement the code above, but, when you or other users want to use that event, they'll be able to add and remove as normal.

This obviously isn't preferred, but, if there's some way I'm not remembering to get an event's delegates, that would be preferred. Another idea would be to add a C# project to your VB.NET project containing the C# code or build the C# code for use in your VB.NET application.

To answer your question about `value.Nodes.CollectionChanged += CollectionChanged;`, it is combining the CollectionChanged delegates of the parent node with the current node. In effect, every single change to the entire tree will raise every child's event handlers, going up the tree. The combining of delegates like that creates a multicast delegate, and, in C#, combining multicast delegates through events is as easy as +=. However, in VB.NET, it seems that AddHandler doesn't convert events into delegates.

Comment: I'm afraid that `value.Nodes.CollectionChanged = [Delegate].Combine(value.Nodes.CollectionChanged, CollectionChanged)` raises an error on each of three of those event references that each is an event and can't be called directly, etc. I'm sure there will be some way to deal with this, but VB's event handling is so wildly different than C#'s that I doubt I'll find it quickly. I can't devote any further work time to this. I'll have another look from home tonight to see if I can get any closer toward working my way out of this VB ghetto... Thanks.

Comment: Did you change the event to a delegate? Just in case I wasn't clear before, in ComboTreeNodeCollection, change the line `Public Event CollectionChanged As NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler` to `Public CollectionChanged As NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't pick up on that at all. VB generally uses the Delegate keyword for delegate declaration, so I'm not sure if your declaration is valid, or if I'm just misunderstanding completely. I'll have to do some reading up on both delegates and events before I can look into working more on this, and I can't devote any more of my working time toward this. I'll just have to have two different ComboBoxes on this form until I have more time to devote to understanding this code properly. Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Those last two lines seem to be causing the new child node to subscribe to the container's CollectionChanged event, then firing the event (because a new child was written to the collection).

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't get it. In VB the syntax to add event handlers is `AddHandler eventName, AddressOf handlerMethod` and I'm familiar with converting C# event handlers to that form. This code has the syntax `AddHandler eventName, AddressOf eventName` which leaves me completely stumped. I've never seen it before, and searching for "subscribing to events" just gets me standard event handler tutorials. Can you provide any further insight?

Answer (score 1):

The thing you're missing here is the definition of the callback which will then delegate back to the event along the lines of this:

```
Public Sub OnCollectionChanged(sender As Object, e As NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs)
   RaiseEvent CollectionChanged(Me, e)
End Sub
```

Also, make sure to add the event object:

```
Public Event CollectionChanged As NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler
```

Then your last couple lines could be

```
 AddHandler value.Nodes.CollectionChanged, AddressOf OnCollectionChanged
 OnCollectionChanged(Me, New NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add))
```

Comment: If you go into the code that OP supplied, CollectionChanged is an event. The indexer is located in the ComboTreeNodeCollection class, and value.Nodes is a ComboTreeNodeCollection.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. See if the revised version works better with the ComboTreeBox.